# Getting an error in MySQL Workbench: Cannot Open Administrator

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-5.6

I'm using local installation of MySQL CE on Windows 7 64-bit.  Tried to use Administrator part for the first time.

[image]

Here's the error I'm getting:

[image: MySQL Workbench Error]

I also see the following in the log:

```
<object db.mgmt.Connection> key=connection could not be resolved
```

This information is probably not enough to diagnose the problem.  Please let me know what I need to post so I can get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an old MySQL Workbench version. Please update to the latest version: http://mysqlworkbench.org/2014/04/whats-new-in-mysql-workbench-6-1/.

In older versions of MySQL Workbench we had connections and management instances separated. So it could happen that you have a server instance without a connection assigned. You could edit that instance to re-assign a connection to make it work.

Since version 6.0 this separation is gone. You only have a connection with all the necessary settings for management too.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.  One more question: MySQL itself is at version 6.5.10.1  Is it fresh enough?

Comment: There's no version 6.5.x for MySQL. The current stable release is 5.6.17 and the next dev version is 5.7.4.

Comment: I accidentally swapped first two numbers. I meant, 5.6.10. 1.. Is there a compelling reason for me to upgrade to the latest?

Comment: That probably depends heavily on your environment, what you need and if you have problems with the current version. If you just want to base your decision on improvements then your best bet is to read up the release notes for each server version. E.g. newer versions always have many bugs fixed, are significantly faster than previous versions and sometimes have new features.